# AssemblyInitialize seems break unit test project in .net 6 (visual studio 2022)

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework, vstest

I have a .net 4.8 unit test project and just migrated it to .net 6.

Although Test explorer shows all tests, when I try to run it in Visual Studio, it just doesn't run anything.
What I found is that as soon as my unit test project contains this AssemblyInitialize attribute, Visual studio just won't run any of the tests.

```
[TestClass]
public class SetupAssemblyInitializer
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as the project is in .net 4.8 and I didn't find any doc saying this attribute doesn't work in .net 6 any more. Is there any workaround or alternative to run some code only once in my Unit Test project?

If I decorate the method with `[ClassInitialize]`, then the project will run without issue. However, this Attribute will not make the method run only once for all tests.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you make any progress?

Comment: I have raised the issue on the mstest Github repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1589

Comment: @afarley thanks for this. I finally worked out the issue myself. The test project was migrated from .net 4.8 to .net 6 and this package reference apparently triggered this issue for me: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform" Version="14.0.0" />. After removing this from project file, my test runs.